# Is there an explanation or documentation for OptaPlanner .ctt file codes?

Tags: optaplanner

In particular, I am trying to customize a .ctt file from the Curriculum Course Scheduling example file to fit my own school's timetable scenario. I could not find any documentation on customizing a .ctt file for import. If you advise another approach, I welcome alternatives. I appreciate any guidance as I am approaching the tool with minimal Java experience. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ctt format description is in the PDF you can download from [the ITC2007 website](http://www.cs.qub.ac.uk/itc2007/curriculmcourse/course_curriculm_index.htm).